# Align Bootstrap rows and columns with its corresponding fields

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to work with bootstrap's responsive column and rows.
I created labels and fields so that I can learn how it works. I'm trying to align the text-fields with its corresponding labels. I was using bootstraps documentation on how to do it, but couldn't figure out the trick.

Why are my fields moving to the bottom and how can I align the text-fields to the corresponding labels.

**Ref:** https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        One
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        two
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        three
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input id="Text1" type="text" placeholder="one" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input id="Text2" type="text" placeholder="two" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input id="Text3" type="text" placeholder="three" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: you are expecting your columns to become rows and your rows to become columns when you resize ?

Comment: The main thing I want is the design to be responsive where the fields and labels match together. I don't know how to do it in bootstrap. @Neil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than having 1, 2, and 3 in a row, you'll need to put both 1s together in a column. So something like this:

```
<div class="col-md-4>
  <p>One</p>
  <input id="Text1" type="text" placeholder="one" />
</div>
<!--insert other columns here-->
```

Comment: thats the answer i also found, and as you are using inputs, you can use the label tag that is made for this ;) and also you can define a constant width for your labels (or paragraphs) in order to have that "grid" look